# How to handle WebClientRequestException?

Tags: spring-boot-admin

How do I handle Spring Exception org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: /192.168.1.2:8080; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /192.168.1.2:8080
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141) ~[spring-webflux-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET health [DefaultWebClient]

Tried using Exception handler and controller advice but not able to

Comment: This means the network connection cannot be opened.
This can have many reasons, like wrong port, application not running, firewall blocking requests, ...
You would need to provide more details for further analysis.